# Style Existing Class (PHP Echo)

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I am attempting to change the text of an existing class with the results from my form submission I created using PHP.

```
<h5 class="when-text"> Form not submitted </h5>
```

exists in my index.php file under the body tag.

In my php tag I have my form submission code, which collects data from a user. After that is submitted, I would like to echo out the results and change the h5 class "Form not submitted" to "Form Submitted" while keeping the same styling / positioning I already have locked in with the class.

I tried using:

```
echo '<h5 class="when-text"> Form submitted! </h5>';
```

That didn't seem to work. It is echoining out the data on top of website, ultimately creating another header.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] to switch behavior within your code.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"):
    ?><h5 class="when-text"> Form submitted</h5><?php
else:
    ?><h5 class="when-text"> Form not submitted</h5><?php
endif;
```

For this method to work you will have to set the method of the form to `POST`

Answer (score 1):

Put a hidden `input` in your form,

```
<form action="" method="post">
 --------
 --------
 <input type="hidden" name="process" value="1" />
</form>
```

Then, instead echoing in your php file, use the following code in your html file to show the `h5`.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['process']) && ($_POST['process'] == 1)): ?>
 <h5 class="when-text"> Form submitted! </h5>
<?php else: ?>
 <h5 class="when-text"> Form not submitted </h5> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

If your form is submitted by the user, `$_POST['process']` will be 1

Answer (score 0):

You could better use jquery for that. When the form has successfully been submitted add the following code to it:

```
$(".when-text").html("Form submitted");
```

Make sure you include jquery library before doing this